# Cannot use an EntityTransaction while using JTA. Using non-jta

Tags: java, jpa, jta

I'm trying to do a CRUD and my persistence.xml have non-JTA-data-source but when I try to do something like create, update or delete I receive a message that says: Cannot use an EntityTransaction while using JTA

An example of muy code:

```
@Transactional
public void destroy(T entity) throws Exception
{
    EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
    try
    {
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.remove(em.merge(entity));
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        em.getTransaction().rollback();
        throw new Exception(e);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (em.isOpen()) 
        {
            em.close();
        }
    }
}
```

My persistence:

```
<persistence-unit name="namePU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <non-jta-data-source>database</non-jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties/>
    </persistence-unit>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the `Transactional` annotation, it seems you are using Spring's transaction management. In that case, there is no point in trying to manually control the transaction via `em.getTransaction()`. Also, I don't know how you get the `EntityManager`, but that may interfere with Spring's transaction management as well.

Either stick to the Spring way of declarative transaction management (IMHO better idea), or remove `Transactional` and `EntityManager` injection and manage the PU and transactions yourself.